# How to not return to where the program left off before an interrupt

Tags: arduino

I am making an alarm. I want it to play a tune once it is time to sound the alarm. I want it to be stopped by a button press.

I have the tune working, and it sounds the alarm when i want it to. But when i press the button, i cannot get the alarm to stop.

There doesn't seem to be much that I can see online on this topic. Some confused me by saying that it can be done with a "while" loop and others say it can be done with a "for" loop, and others say that you need to check at specific points in your code to see if the button had been pressed after the interrupt. (a volatile variable would be changed during the interrupt)

I do not think putting checkpoints for the button being pressed after the interrupt is an elegant solution and the file size would be too big to hold the full tune. (96% of the space has been used up with the full tune)

I had a few attempts.

the first attempt didn't try to fix the issue but was a workaround. it would basically keep the Arduino busy indefinitely during the interrupt. It's bad practice, but it would at least stop the alarm.

```
int tonePin = 11;
boolean button_was_pressed = false;
void donothing(){
  while(button_was_pressed)
  {bool who_cares_this_is_just_to_keep_the_cpu_busy;}}
void isr()
{
  button_was_pressed = true;
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  donothing();
}

void setup() {
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), isr, RISING);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void midi() {
  
  Serial.println("midi");
  Serial.println(millis());
    tone(tonePin, 207, 3595.840371094);
    delay(3627.200390625);
    delay(150.197988281);
    tone(tonePin, 220, 578.592360352);
    delay(609.044589844);
    delay(275.638066406);
    tone(tonePin, 207, 578.592360352);
    delay(609.044589844);
    delay(240.976992188);
      
  Serial.println("midi exit");
  Serial.println(millis());
//(the actual tune isnt so bland and short. this tune was for debugging purposes)
  
}



void loop() {
  
 unsigned long period = 15*1000L;//the period is 15 seconds (can easily be replaced with 24 hrs once the issue is solved)
 
  Serial.println("loop");
  Serial.println(millis());
  Serial.println(millis() % period);
  //wait till morning
  
digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
delay(100);
 //unsigned long hbhb = 15*1000L; //15 sec


 if(millis() % period < 100)
 {
  
    midi();
  
 }
```

i have other attempts trying to call a different function but after the interrupt, it always returns to where it left off.

how can i stop playing the song without needing to keep the program busy and not interfering with the next alarm?

Comment: Try reading the datasheet, the copious online documentation, the Arduino source and any of hundreds of Atmel application notes.  There literally are no secrets, it just takes effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, delay takes an integer.  No decimal places.  If you want finer timing you can use delayMicroseconds and use microseconds, but it still only takes integer values.  The same goes for the duration argument for tone.

As for your actual question, it simply cannot be done with this code.  You have written blocking code.  Google that term.  When you use delay to handle the timing, then that's all you are going to be able to do.  You can't read buttons.  Newbies love to try to solve this problem with an interrupt but as you just learned that doesn't work.  What you need is non-blocking code.  Think of a midi() function that instead of being called once and playing all the way through the alarm instead gets called over and over every few microseconds and most of the time just checks to see if it is time to change the note or if the button is pressed and does nothing, but occasionally sees that it is time to change the note or that the button is pressed and changes the note or stops it entirely.  You will have to change from delay to handling the timing with millis().  Have a look at the Blink Without Delay example and any of the thousands of great tutorials on how it works to get some inspiration on how to do that.

Your ISR is also a huge problem.  Let's look at that. An ISR should be super fast.  In and out in a few microseconds.   But yours calls this function:

```
void donothing(){
  while(button_was_pressed)
  {bool who_cares_this_is_just_to_keep_the_cpu_busy;}}
```

Since nothing inside that while loop ever changes the value of button_was_pressed, this is an infinite loop.  Actually, there's nothing in the entire code that will ever set button_was_pressed back to false.  I'm not sure how you expected this to work, but it doesn't.

The proper solution for this issue will not involve interrupts at all.  Interrupts are for super fast things that happen so quickly that they might be missed.  Remember that all the other interrupts are off while inside the ISR, so millis stops counting and serial stops working and lots of things that need to happen don't happen in there.

Unless you can press and release a button in a matter of microseconds (an eye blink takes around 200,000 microseconds for comparison) then an interrupt is not really appropriate for catching a button press.  If you do this right there will be no interrupt involved in your code.  In most all situations you should be trying to avoid having to use an interrupt.  They almost always make things harder.  Use them as a last resort for pulses too short to catch, not humans pressing buttons.

Comment: the delay function was a copy paste from a "midi to arduino" site. and it seemed to work so i didnt bother changing it. ill look up blocking and non-blocking, thanks. also, there was no way to change back "button_was_pressed" because its only purpose was to stop the alarm by keeping the while loop going. bad practice but it got the point across i know.

Comment: hey, i just wanna say thanks. I made it more "non-blocky" and it seems to run well. i had to make a new program that will go through the auto-generated code of a midi file and put it into an array. that was actually pretty fun. And from what I can see, it all works aside from a weird stuttering issue. thanks again